# Pages templates for Resumes

Tags: pages, iwork

I'm looking for some Pages templates for Resume (software developer CV).
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are built-in resume templates in Pages. Select `File > New from Template Chooser`

Comment: Yeah I know about this one, I'm looking for extra templates.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the built-in templates, you can find some good ones elsewhere.

- [iWork Community](http://www.iworkcommunity.com/) has some resume
  templates.
- Jumsoft makes and sells really nice templates for many purposes. Look at both their [regular](http://www.jumsoft.com/pages/) and [Pro](http://www.jumsoft.com/pagespro/) Pages templates.
- There's a perhaps-too-fashionable resume template [here](http://iworktemplates.blogspot.com/2010/12/pages-09-resume-template.html).